# JS semantics: Why do private and public class properties seem to get reordered?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, semantics, private-members

The screenshot below shows the value of `new A()`, but its properties were reordered.

Is there any good reason for this?

### Code

```js
class A {
  constructor() { }
  #private1 = 1;
  public1 = 11;

  #private2 = 2;
  public2 = 22;
}

new A();
```

### Result:

[image]

Comment: It's always a bad idea to rely on specific ordering of properties. So, why exactly do you find this alarming more than the actual expectation for a given order?

Comment: It's `this.#privateX` not `this.privateX`… The latter **is** `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ The idea that things are recorded in order of execution is not a far-fetched idea, is it now? It works for local variables. Why does it not work for class fields? I cannot find any reference in the specs that say that this is an invalid assumption (but of course, I might not have been looking hard enough).

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @Domi The order of execution is the order of the initialiser definitions in the `class`, but the display of the object in the console is unordered. (And even if properties are ordered, private fields are not part of that order).

Comment: @Domi No, I just voted to close as a typo :P

Comment: @Bergi Is it only a typo though? The "order" part, while separate from the observed problem, is still worth explaining, no? - Especially considering that the question itself refers to "order" not "why is it undefined?"

Comment: @Domi But that's not what the question is about, no? "*Problem: In the following code sample, `this.privateX` is undefined*" appears to be the central part of your question. If it isn't, please [edit] to remove the typo and focus on the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private members are not normal properties (that are keyed with strings or symbols), they do not share an ordering where they can be interspersed arbitrarily.

In fact, private members are not enumerable at all, so you can never list them in *any* order. There is just no JS functionality to do that.

The devtools (which access the object using the debugger API) apparently chose to list first the properties of the object, then the private fields of the object, in the order in which they were defined. Notice this might change at any time, you should not ascribe it any significance.

Comment: Really looking forward to seeing a change to the spec that ultimately allows enumerating private members ([as discussed here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields/issues/94)).

Comment: @Domi Private members are by design not dynamically accessible. And there is no reflection for them, because they're really private. JS doesn't work like C#. If you really need to loop, loop over `[o => o.#private1, o => o.#private2]`.

Comment: Sadly, that is not "looping over", and also, you mean `this` instead of `o`, no? (I think, `o.#private1` is not valid syntax?)
You pointed out in another thread that `eval` can do it, but that still requires a list of all possible variables. Right now, the only way of extracting that information without `babel` et al, seems to be regexing `MyClass.toString`, but that is of course very bug-prone...

Comment: @Domi Just don't use private fields then.